# Convert text duration into formatted duration in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to convert a column of durations pulled from an outside source at formats as a text base duration(Ex. 0h 2m 52s 733ms) into a duration that i can use in formulas with other durations.

I have tried trimming but run into issues as sometimes the minutes are 2 digits and milliseconds are from 1-999

What i'm hoping to accomplish:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0h 2m 52s 733ms | 0:03:34 | B - A |

[Here's what i'm hoping to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvmGQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in Column Cell C2

```
= B2-(
  trim(left(A2,search("h",$A$2)-1))
  &":"&
  trim(mid($A$2,search("h",$A$2)+2,search("m",$A$2)-search("h",$A$2)-2))
  &":"&
  trim(mid($A$2,search("m",$A$2)+2,search("s",$A$2)-search("m",$A$2)-2))
  )
```

---

**Logic**

This formula uses the long-hand, old-school method:

- find the index of the various identification letters in the string

  - **hours**: `search("h",$A$2)`
  - **minutes**: `search("m",$A$2)`
  - **second**: `search("s",$A$2)`
- use the index values to extract the relevant value

  - **Hours**: `trim(left($A$2,hours-1))`
  - **Minutes**: `trim(mid($A$2,hours+2,minutes-hours-2))`
  - **Seconds**: `trim(mid($A$2,minutes+2,seconds-minutes-2))`
- combine the values

  - `= Hours&":"&Minutes&":"&Seconds`

---

**Results**

[image]